# Javascript iframe not load in bootstrap popup (modal)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

I've try to load `WYSIWYG` editor in bootstrap modal but that `iframe` is not load as below.

```
<iframe id="desc_ifr" frameborder="0" src="javascript:""" allowtransparency="true" style="width: 100%; height: 410px; display: block;">
<html>
<head></head>
<body></body>
</html>
</iframe>
```

How can I load that `iframe` ? Is that possible? 
I know out side `iframe` can load in below methoad.

```
$('.modal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(){  
  $(this).find('iframe').attr('src','http://www.google.com')
})
```

Any suggestions ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Miuranga**, have a look  at the code in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1f6dwxn0/)** and see if you can get it into your WYSIWYG, I don't use one so not sure if you can just copy the code into it.

But the way to get a iframe into a modal is in the code.

Just note that in the Fiddle, the code actually displays in a iframe and I'm sure you can not have a `iframe` in another `iframe`. They will not show the url you want to display. I have tested it and it does work.
Also some urls like google.com are restricted to display in iframes.
This is why I used microsoft.com.

View the Run Code Snippet below.

```html
<html>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" >  


<body>
    
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#incidentModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
    
    
    
    
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade  bs-example-modal-lg" id="incidentModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header  bg-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal Title</h4>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-header -->
    <!--/.modal-header -->
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="modal-body row">
                <iframe id="desc_ifr" src="http://microsoft.com" style="width: 100%; height: 410px;" allowtransparency="true" >
                </iframe>          
            </div>
            
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid-->
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-body-->
    <div class="modal-footer bg-info">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-footer -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-content-->
</div>
<!-- /.modal-dialog modal-lg-->
</div>
<!-- /.modal fade  bs-example-modal-lg -->
            
          <!--  </span></button></div></div>       -->   
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>            
</body>
</html>
```